# How to come back on the start fragment from the 2_nd,3_rd fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

Here is my code
I need to  go from A->B->C and onBackPressed() from B and C should go to A
while pressing back it goes to B and then to C , It seems to me that transaction.addToBackStack(null); not using as needed

```
public class TestfragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private FrameLayout layout;
private String TAG = "TAG";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_fragment);
    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    A fragment = new A();
    doFragmentTransaction(fragment, false);
}

private void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    if (addToBackstack)
        transaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
    transaction.commit();
}
///////////////
public class A extends Fragment {
private Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment1, null);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            B fragment = new B();
            doFragmentTransaction(fragment, true);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


private void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

    if (addToBackstack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}



//////////////////////


public class B extends Fragment {
private Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment2, null);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            C fragment = new C();
            doFragmentTransaction(fragment, false);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void doFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackstack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

    if (addToBackstack)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

in fragment B and C,

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

in the function, replace the Container with Fragment A.

Comment: How could I replace with Fragment A ,without creating Fragment A again and replacing with transactions?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new fragment? To be in last current state?

Comment: I don't want to create ,but to go to the first fragment ?